# How to control what a camera sees in Android

Tags: java, android

I need to control the camera in an android smart-phone, I mean that any time the camera turns on, the screen should show an image or video that I choose.

For example, when I open the *Whatsapp* application and click to capture a picture the camera will show up but without capturing, its will only show the image / video that I chose.

I haven't tried anything so far, because I really don't have any idea about how to do it. I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: According to [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/124752/4229) on [android.se] there are apps which do this, so the question is, do you want to understand how these apps work, or do you just want an app that will do it for you?

Comment: it is  not possible (without root access) and should stay impossible

Comment: I want tl know how to do it..its ok with root access